# C# changing DataGridView cell Type (error?)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView linked to a DataTable.
The cells in the table are set to decimal.

In the case of no relevant data, I wish to diaply "No Data" text in the "power" column (#2) rather than the value.

For that, I do the following:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in resultsDataGrid.Rows)
  if ((int)row.Cells["DataYN"].Value == 1)
  {
    row.Cells["Power"].ValueType = typeof(String);  
    row.Cells["Power"].Value = "No Data";  
  }
```

When compiling, I get an error message ' "*No Data" is not a valid value for Decimal*....'.

The cell Value Type is clearly set and shown as string, yet the compiler thinks it is still decimal.
I have tried all kinds of casting and conversion, but for no avail.

1. Is this a compiler error ?
2. Is there a workaround?

samtal

Comment: when compiling? are you sure? or when running? the compiler should not really know the loosely type value type.

Comment: how about using SetValue() ? it should box it in the object type without any issues.

Comment: Right, it is when debugging, which is running. Sorry.
I have tried SetValue, but I get another, additional problem: In SetValue one must insert the full row (of objects), but I only wish to change one cell in one column (#2). I have tried nulls, casting to Object, etc., but get errors(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.setvalues.aspx) 

Whatever I do, the system still insists the cells keep their original Type, and will not accept a string or an Object.
I still believe it is a bug, and still looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of actually trying to change the value of the cell, why not specify "No Data" as the NullValue property of the cell's default style (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.nullvalue.aspx).  This would eliminate the need to loop through the data and should prevent the grid from trying to convert the value to a decimal.

Comment: Thanks.
The NullValue is a good cure for cells that have no data. My cells have all default data, thus not null.
In addition, the problem I described (Cells Type is solid strong - will not enable casting or changing) persists even with default Null value set (Tested as suggested).
As I wrote, unless I totally misunderstood the properties, it seems to be a bug (?). 
(VS2010 Express, Win7 64)

Comment: @user2279419 For any given column in a `DataGridView`, values can only be of the column's data type, or `DbNull`/`null`.  You can't mix data types.

Comment: thanks erdomke - 
By fact, you seem to be right.
I can change the type of a single cell from its default Decimal by row.Cells[2].ValueType = typeof(String), as can be seen in the debugger, but when entering actual string data into the cell, it throws Type error.
This is a strange situation in VS with conflicting behavior.
Furthermore, I searched MS VS documentation and could not find any explicit limitation to the type, namely saying that the type must be the same in all rows (cells) in a given column.
I gave up, unless someone can come with a smart workaround.

Comment: OK. 
I have now new understanding of the error.
If changing the Type to String, the cell will accept any string format that can be converted or parsed to number, but not pure text.
The error message indicates that it can not convert the string to Decimal.

Comment: Just as an FYI, you can customize the parsing and formatting behavior of the DataGridView via the `CellParsing` and `CellFormatting` events (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx).